# Download all files of a given type(.dll) from a http path in C#

Tags: c#, dll, reference

There are similar questions regarding this which were asked earlier. But I couldn't find a proper solution yet.
I have an application which uses a user defined dll library(Cplus_Function_Library.dll). Imagine that the application is launched already to customers. And if there's a new version of the dll available the application will automatically download it and replaces the old one. There's no problem there.

Now I want to create new dll libraries(a lot) and upload it in the sameplace where the Cplus_Function_Library.dll new version exsists(ex: http path/FTP server). And then I can add them by reference in the Cplus_Function_Library.dll. It's also clear. **But my question is how can I download all the dll files in this path without giving the file names one by one inside my updater function?** Because when I launch the app these files are not known.(updater function is included inside the application.)Is there an easy way to download all the dll files from a specified path without much hassle?

My current update function can be seen below.

```
    Uri pathToNewVerNo = new Uri("//....../New_version.txt"); //Path to the new version number
    Uri pathToCurrentVerNo = new Uri("...../Current_version.txt"); //Path to the current version number
    Uri pathToDownload = new Uri(".....new_library.dll");
    StreamReader readNewVer; //To read the new version number
    StreamReader readCurVer; //To read the current version number
    StreamWriter writeToCurVer;
    WebClient verNew = new WebClient(); //will be used to download the New_version .txt file
    WebClient verCur = new WebClient(); //will be used to download the Current_version .txt file
    WebClient update = new WebClient(); //will be used to download the new dll file
    verNew.DownloadFile(pathToNewVerNo, "New_version.txt"); //Download the New_version .txt file
    readCurVer = new StreamReader("Current_version.txt"); //open Current_version.txt file to read
    current_Version = readCurVer.ReadLine(); //assign the value to a string
    readCurVer.Close(); //close the file 
    readNewVer = new StreamReader("New_version.txt"); //open New_version.txt file to read  
    new_Version = readNewVer.ReadLine(); //assign the value to a string
    readNewVer.Close(); //close the file
    current_ver_doub = Convert.ToDouble(current_Version); //convert the string value to a double
    new_ver_doub = Convert.ToDouble(new_Version);

    if (new_ver_doub > current_ver_doub) //check if the new version number is greater than the current version number
    {
        obj.SBO_Application.StatusBar.SetText("Please wait update in process", BoMessageTime.bmt_Medium, BoStatusBarMessageType.smt_Warning);
        writeToCurVer = new StreamWriter("Current_version.txt"); //open the current_version.txt to write
        writeToCurVer.Write(new_Version); //update with new version number
        writeToCurVer.Close(); //close the file
        update.DownloadFile(pathToDownload, "new_library.dll"); //download the new .dll file



        //*************There will be a roll back functionality added in the future in case if the updated dll file is currupted.*****************
        File.Replace("new_library.dll", "Cplus_Function_Library.dll", "Cplus_Function_Library.dll.bac", false); //make a back up file of the old .dll file and replace it

        obj.SBO_Application.MessageBox("Update Successful. Please restart the AddOn", 1, "Ok");

        try
        {
            foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("cplus_Global"))
            {
                proc.Kill();
                proc.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj.SBO_Application.MessageBox(ex.Message, 1, "Ok");
        } 



    }
    else
    {
        //  SBO_Application.MessageBox("No Update Available", 1, "Ok");
    }

}//End of updater_cplus function   */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to ask yourself whether you absolutely want to reinvent the wheel, and are ready to tackle all problems you will encounter while doing that, such as the problem you now ran into. There are plenty of existing solutions to include installers and updaters with your software.

Anyway, to answer your question:

> how can I download all the dll files in this path without giving the file names one by one inside my updater function?

You casually mention it should work over HTTP and FTP. The former has no formal "directory listing" command, so you'll have to invent that yourself. The latter does, but requires the directory to only contain relevant files, or you need to create a whitelist and/or blacklist to include or exclude certain files.

The easiest solution would be to define your version file format so as to include the list of files to download. Then you fetch the version file, interpret it and request the files mentioned in it.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It sounds good. I'll try to use an approach like that. About the other installers/updaters: Most of these replace the executable file which changes the checksum. And in SAP the addons don't work after you change the checksum. That's why I had to come up with a different solution like this.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to CodeCaster's idea I put all my dll files inside one folder and the new_version text file in another folder. This way I made sure different file formats won't get mixed up.

The next step was to read the new_version.txt from the ftp server and compare the value with the current version. If it's greater than the later I took all the file names of dll files to a list. Then easily you can download the files one by one to your desired location.